# how to add simple searching yii2

Tags: search, yii2

I have to make a simple searching in my index view.
The data to be searched in the table is not a grid view but a regular table.
How can I add a simple searching like this?

[image: this is the interface]

And this is the code in **index view**

Search

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">NIP</th>
        <th class="text-center">Nama Pegawai</th>
        <th class="text-center">Jumlah Dokumen</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($models as $data): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $data["nip"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $data["nama"] ?></td>
        <td align = "center"><?= $data["jumlah"] ?></td>
        <td width = "200 px" align = "center"><a class = "btn btn-success" href = "./?r=arsip-sdm/detail&id=<?= $data['nip'] ?>">Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And this is the code in **controller**

[image]

help me please

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate filter form

eg :

```
<div class="post-search">
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
   ]); ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'creation_date') ?>

  <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
  </div>

 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

perform a render partial in your view and use the normal 'searchModel' => $searchModel, in your you  gridView config

you can see some sample here

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#separate-filter-form

Comment: the data to be searched in the table is not a grid view but a regular table. that's what drives me crazy. can you give me another solution? thank you very much

Comment: why you don't use a grdiview  .. with a proper style???  you can configure the aspect of the gridview like your "regular table"